# Dropdown Box shows as blank instead of pulling items from the Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

For some reason, my PHP code won't show up database in the drop down box that I retrieve from MySQL. `CS_JOBS` and `CS_JOBS_CATEGORY` are tables in the database. I join `CS_JOBS_CATEGORY` and `CS_JOBS`, since they both have the same `category_code` column. I already tested `connect.php`, it's working fine.

```
<?php 

   require("connect.php");

   $sql = "SELECT category_name FROM CS_JOBS_CATEGORY";
   $result = mysql_query($sql);
   echo "<select name='category_name'>";
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo "<option value='".$row['category_name']."'>".$row['category_name']."</option>";
   }
   echo "</select>";

?>
```

My goal is to show all `category_name` in the drop down box. Every time a user clicks on each `category_name`, it will show up all `jobs(CS_JOBS)` in each category. `CS_JOBS` consists of `job_order_number`, `location`, `date_close` ..etc..

Comment: Do some debugging on your code. Does your query work? Does it pull back any data?

Comment: are you getting an error message?

Comment: @sgroves: It's only show up the drop down up with blank items in there. I have tried to test the connect.php, it works just fine.

Comment: @Strawberry: Have tried to test this code?

Comment: Yes - hence my response. Assuming you have a file called connect.php with basic connection statements, and a table cs_jobs_category with a column called category_name, then this code works as expected.

Comment: @Bunchhieng - try a `var_dump($result)` after the query, and `var_dump($row)` inside your loop

Comment: Finally it's working now. I forgot to put s after name, category_names. stupid mistake. Thanks.

Comment: The code is working just fine. I didn't realize I forgot to put a **"s"** after name which is **`category_names`**. Stupid mistake. I was wondering if there anyway I can link a **submit button** to my drop down box, so when user choose one name it will show up all jobs based on **`CS_JOBS`** table. Thanks!!